# How do I write a loop that ask for a number and operator but end with "=", and also, I need to use a String to store the entered formula

Tags: java, loops

This is the output that i need:

```
Enter number: 6

Choose an operator (+ or – or * or =) : *

Enter number: 10

Choose an operator (+ or – or * or =) : +

Enter number: 5

Choose an operator (+ or – or * or =) : =

Answer:

6 * 10 + 5 = 65
```

This is my program：

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator1 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int input = 0;
        String a = abc.nextLine();
        while(input >= 0){
            switch(a) {    
                case "+":
                    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(sum+input);
                    continue;
            
                case "-":
                    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(sum-input);       
                    continue;

                case "*":
                    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(input*sum);
                    continue;
                
                case "=":
                    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print(sum);
                    break;            
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you seeing? Does the code throw an error or does it simply not produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be improved in your code.

- Nowhere in the code do you ask for the first number.
- You do not need two scanners for System.in.
- More descriptive variable names would help.

The code below fixes the first two issues:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator1{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int input = 0;
        String a = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        sum = scan.nextInt();
while(input >= 0){
    System.out.print("Choose an operator (+ or - or * or = ): ");
    a = scan.next();
    switch(a) {

          case "+":
           System.out.print("Enter number: ");
           input = scan.nextInt();
           sum += input;
           //System.out.println(sum+input);
        continue;
            
     case "-":
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            sum -= input;
            //System.out.println(sum-input);       
        continue;

     case "*":
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        sum *= input;
        //System.out.println(input*sum);
        continue;
                
         case "=":
            System.out.println(sum);
            break;            
    }
    //System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println("Enter -1 to stop or 0 to keep going: ");
    input = scan.nextInt();
    }
}}
```

Comment: I'd replace ```sum``` variable name to ```result``` since not only the add operation is involved

Comment: Thank you very much for your willingness to guide me, and I'm very sorry if my English is not so good.

Comment: I wanted to do it exactly same like below structure, but i am not sure if i am correct or not.
1. Write a loop to do the following:
a) Ask for a number
b) Ask to choose an operator, enter “=” to finish the loop
c) Calculate the answer based on the selected operator
d) Use a String to store the entered formulae.

2. Display the entered formulae with the answer after the loop is ended.

Comment: You have the code to do that in what I wrote above, but you'll have to move some lines around. Identify which lines of code go with which pieces of your structure and arrange them similarly.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.